# Best way to insert data to BigQuery from NodeJS?

Tags: ajax, node.js, google-bigquery, digital-ocean

We're running a web analytics tool that works like this:

1. AJAX request to a DigitalOcean box with 4 CPUs, running Node and PM2 (to make use of multiple CPUs).  Requests come in rapidly -- many times per second.
2. Using https://www.npmjs.org/package/bigquery, we connect to BigQuery and insert the data from the call

We are dropping events.  A lot of them -- 1/3 or more, sometimes.  My current guess is that the calls come in too quickly for the connection between DigitalOcean and BigQuery to open, insert data, close, and be ready for the another insertion.

We had some errors before that members of Stack helped resolve, but no more errors are regularly occurring.

Does this sound like the most likely cause?

Comment: How quickly is quickly? Do you have a project id?

Comment: 774436620412 -- hopefully, there isn't an issue and it's boneheaded issue on our part!  As for how quickly, we're tracking page loads, scroll events, some time events, and a few other browser actions on about 80k pageviews/day.  High, but not crazy-high, volumes.

Comment: Are you still have this issue ?